# XML DocumentElement is trashing the innerXml

Tags: c#, xml

I have a simple XML file, shown below, which when read-in via a basic XmlDocument.Load(filename.xml). If I load the file, and inspect it's innerXML, it all looks normal. However, when I inspect the value of DocumentElement, it's a mess!!! I kept the example small, so you can easily see there is no mal-formation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fax:FaxService xmlns:fax="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/service/fax/2009/02/11/" xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">
  <fax:ServiceDefaults>
    <fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
      <fax:InternetFaxSettings>
        <dd:FaxFileFormat>MTIFFG4</dd:FaxFileFormat>
        <dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr>false</dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr>
        <dd:AutoCompleteToNANP>false</dd:AutoCompleteToNANP>
        <dd:RetryInterval>0</dd:RetryInterval>
        <dd:MaxRetryAttempts>0</dd:MaxRetryAttempts>
      </fax:InternetFaxSettings>
    </fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
  </fax:ServiceDefaults>
</fax:FaxService>
```

Now, try this in C# with this simple code:

...

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("*XMLSAMPLE.XML*");

textBox1.Text = xDoc.InnerXml;
textBox2.Text = xDoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml;
```

...

It's completely mangled, with the 2nd namespace repeated with every dd tag, and not even included in the top-most tag.

What am I doing wrong? This is driving me nuts!

Comment: It should not change the file semantics, that is, the modified xml is equivalent to the original one. Properyly written tools should not make a difference. Can you explain why is this a problem for you?

Comment: Can you at least give an example of what you would like to see in the text boxes? I think this may be a misunderstanding of how one reads the DOM in C#

Answer (score 1):

The content returned by `xDoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml` is semantically identical to your original `ServiceDefaults` tag - if the first fragment conforms to your XML schema, the InnerXml fragment will also conform to the definition of the inner element.  Just because the framework has re-arranged the namespace declarations does not change the semantics of the document.

[Compare the output](http://ideone.com/XB7aH) of your the two XmlDocument properties:

`xDoc.DocumentElement`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <fax:FaxService xmlns:fax="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/service/fax/2009/02/11/" xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">
    <fax:ServiceDefaults>
     <fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
      <fax:InternetFaxSettings>
        <dd:FaxFileFormat>MTIFFG4</dd:FaxFileFormat>
        <dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr>false</dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr>
        <dd:AutoCompleteToNANP>false</dd:AutoCompleteToNANP>
        <dd:RetryInterval>0</dd:RetryInterval>
        <dd:MaxRetryAttempts>0</dd:MaxRetryAttempts>
      </fax:InternetFaxSettings>
     </fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
    </fax:ServiceDefaults>
  </fax:FaxService>
```

`xDoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml`:

```
<fax:ServiceDefaults xmlns:fax="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/service/fax/2009/02/11/">
  <fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
   <fax:InternetFaxSettings>
     <dd:FaxFileFormat xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">MTIFFG4</dd:FaxFileFormat>
     <dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">false</dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr>
     <dd:AutoCompleteToNANP xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">false</dd:AutoCompleteToNANP>
     <dd:RetryInterval xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">0</dd:RetryInterval>
     <dd:MaxRetryAttempts xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">0</dd:MaxRetryAttempts>
   </fax:InternetFaxSettings>
  </fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
 </fax:ServiceDefaults>
```

Answer (score 1):

A look at the following link in MSDN will help shed light on your situation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.innerxml.aspx

Basically, `xDoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml` is looking at the `<fax:ServiceDefaults>` node, whereas `xDoc.InnerXml` is looking one level higher (`FaxService` node). This is crucial to understanding your problem - because all of your `xmlns` is on the `FaxService` node.

Make the following change to your XML document, and notice what happens (basically, copy over the xmlns info to the `ServiceDefaults` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fax:FaxService xmlns:fax="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/service/fax/2009/02/11/" xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">
  <fax:ServiceDefaults xmlns:fax="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/service/fax/2009/02/11/" xmlns:dd="http://www.hp.com/schemas/imaging/con/dictionaries/1.0/">
    <fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
      <fax:InternetFaxSettings>
        <dd:FaxFileFormat>MTIFFG4</dd:FaxFileFormat>
        <dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr>false</dd:UseEmailAsFaxAcctAddr>
        <dd:AutoCompleteToNANP>false</dd:AutoCompleteToNANP>
        <dd:RetryInterval>0</dd:RetryInterval>
        <dd:MaxRetryAttempts>0</dd:MaxRetryAttempts>
      </fax:InternetFaxSettings>
    </fax:ServiceSendDefaults>
  </fax:ServiceDefaults>
</fax:FaxService>
```

Suddenly your code will behave according to your expectations. So hopefully this helps you towards understanding the issue. What the permanent fix should be, that's up to you.

HTH!